# How do I make footnote (bigfoot) to work properly in title and author fields?

Tags: titles

We always need to put two types of footnotes for historical documents, one for publishing notes, another for contents, so package `bigfoot` is a good choice. Sometimes, only write comments for main content is not enough, we need comments for title and author, too.

But, since footnote is not compatible with `maketitle`, and normally people use `\thanks` to comment about the authors, it can't be accomplished. This there a way to workaround the limitation, e.g. define a new `maketitle`?

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{Publish}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote{Content}[roman]

\title{Observation of Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen Entanglement 
on Supraquantum Structures by Induction Through 
Nonlinear\footnotePublish{Original draft was "linear", 
seems a mistake.} Transuranic Crystal of ELW\footnoteContent{Extremely 
Long Wavelength} Pulse from Mode-Locked Source Array}

\author{Black Mesa Research\footnoteContent{Gordon Freeman is 
believed as the author.} Facility\footnotePublish{Original draft 
was "Agency", changed to offical name.}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

As you see, the footnote doesn't work properly (compiled by XeLaTeX), the spaces between labels and words are too small, and the notes for the author are not displayed.

[image: Rendered PDF Document]

Comment: i don't know whether there is anything comparable for `bigfoot`, but basic latex provides `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` for situations like this.

Comment: @barbarabeeton There's no benefit in using `\footnotemark`, because the problem is in the redefinition of `\@makefnmark` that happens during processing of `\maketitle`.

Comment: @egreg -- okay.  i do remember that we've used it here with `amsart`, but we probably had to do some local hackery to get the needed result, and it wouldn't be easy to find.  (never mind that the top matter of `amsart` is quite different from that of `article`.)  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `article` class assumes that footnotes in the title are for “thanks” and appear at the end of the title, not counting for its centering.

You can avoid this by making it not redefining `\@makefnmark`; since it says `\def\@makefnmark{...}`, I change it into `\def\aaaBBBcccDDD{...}` that is unlikely to be found in your title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{bigfoot}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\@makefnmark}{\aaaBBBcccDDD}{}{}
\makeatother
\DeclareNewFootnote{Publish}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote{Content}[roman]

\title{Observation of Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen Entanglement
on Supraquantum Structures by Induction Through
Nonlinear\footnotePublish{Original draft was "linear",
seems a mistake.} Transuranic Crystal of ELW\footnoteContent{Extremely
Long Wavelength} Pulse from Mode-Locked Source Array}

\author{Black Mesa Research\footnoteContent{Gordon Freeman is
believed as the author.} Facility\footnotePublish{Original draft
was "Agency", changed to offical name.}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ciao egreg, nice one :-)